# Selecting Latest Record from a Union identified by the table it came from

Tags: mysql, sql, max, union

please see below.

```
my Data Set:
tsl dte     | sales | inserton |Mode
03-01-18    |1000   | 03-01-18 | A
03-01-18    |2000   | 03-05-18 | M
03-02-18    |0.00   | 03-02-18 | A
03-02-18    |1500   | 03-08-18 | A
03-03-18    |0.00   | 03-03-18 | A
03-03-18    |0.00   | 03-03-18 | M
03-03-18    |0.00   | 03-03-18 | M
03-03-18    |1500   | 03-08-18 | M
03-04-18    |2600   | 03-04-18 | A
```

What I want to be filtered

```
tsl dte     | sales | inserton |Mode
03-01-18    |2000   | 03-05-18 | M
03-02-18    |1500   | 03-08-18 | A
03-03-18    |1500   | 03-08-18 | M
03-04-18    |2600   | 03-04-18 | A
```

How can I get the latest record sent, using a `UNION` of two tables:

`SalesDetail` (Auto Sending)

`SalesDetailManual`  (Manual Sending).

I've highlighted the row I want:

[image]

Comment: Seems the two answers you've received are not providing you the results you desire. Edit your post and provide the queries to rebuild the schema you are working with, such as DDL (`CREATE TABLE. . .`) and DML (`INSERT. . .`) commands for the two tables and a very specific **exact** representation of what you want the result to be.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

Here is one quick way to do this in MySQL:

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT *, 'SalesDetail' AS source
    FROM SalesDetail
    UNION ALL
    SELECT *, 'SalesDetailManual'
    FROM SalesDetailManual
) t
ORDER BY insertOn DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Note carefully that I add a computed column `source` to both subqueries to keep track of the source for each table.

Comment: Ahh I see, instead of the `A` or `M` (Automatic vs Manual), you have indicated which query is represented. I like.

Comment: hi, i also need other (tsl_dte)s. just in the example, the latest for March 1 (tsl_dte) is the one sent on March 8 (inserton).

Comment: @RichardRoque **Edit** your question and show us clear sample input and sample output.  You probably don't need to show us all those columns.  Just a few is fine, and also **don't** paste images of data, show us text instead.

Comment: hi sirs, please see below.

my Data Set:
tsl dte  | sales | inserton |Mode
03-01-18 |1000 | 03-01-18 | A
03-01-18 |2000 | 03-05-18 | M
03-02-18 |0.00 | 03-02-18 | A
03-02-18 |1500 | 03-08-18 | A
03-03-18 |0.00 | 03-03-18 | A
03-03-18 |0.00 | 03-03-18 | M
03-03-18 |0.00 | 03-03-18 | M
03-03-18 |1500 | 03-08-18 | M
03-04-18 |2600 | 03-04-18 | A

What I want to be filtered

tsl dte  | sales | inserton |Mode
03-01-18 |2000 | 03-05-18 | M
03-02-18 |1500 | 03-08-18 | A
03-03-18 |1500 | 03-08-18 | M
03-04-18 |2600 | 03-04-18 | A

Comment: I will remove the downvote when you edit your question and put the data there.